# Automapper inner model attribute returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

so I have an entity model using Entity Framework Core which is used in ASP.NET Core Web API.

I have created two entity models:

```
public class FishCategory
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Fish> Fish { get; set; }
}

public class Fish
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float WeightKg { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public FishCategory Category { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public User Seller { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

These 2 entities have one to many relationship

Then here is the 2 DTO models for both of the entities

```
public class FishReadDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public float WeightKg { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public FishCategoryReadDTO Category { get; set; }
    public UserReadDTO Seller { get; set; }
}

public class FishCategoryReadDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Here the repository for the Fish entity model

```
public Fish GetFishById(int id)
{
    return _databaseContext.Fishes
        .Where(fish => fish.ID.Equals(id))
        .Select(fish => new Fish()
        {
            ID = fish.ID,
            Category = fish.Category,
            CategoryID = fish.CategoryID,
            Description = fish.Description,
            Item = fish.Item,
            Name = fish.Name,
            Price = fish.Price,
            Seller = fish.Seller,
            Stock = fish.Stock,
            UserID = fish.UserID,
            WeightKg = fish.WeightKg
        }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Here's the Profile class for the DTO

```
public class EFishingProfile : Profile
{
    public EFishingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserReadDTO>();
        CreateMap<FishCategory, FishCategoryReadDTO>();
        CreateMap<Fish, FishReadDTO>();


        CreateMap<FishCreateDTO, Fish>();
    }
}
```

Here's the controller that executes this method to get the data

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetFishById")]
public ActionResult<FishReadDTO> GetFishById(int id)
{
    var fish = _repository.GetFishById(id);
    if(fish == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(_mapper.Map<FishReadDTO>(fish));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Fish> CreateFish(FishCreateDTO fishCreateDTO)
{
    var fishModel = _mapper.Map<Fish>(fishCreateDTO);
    _repository.CreateFish(fishModel);

    var fishRead = _mapper.Map<FishReadDTO>(fishModel);

    return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetFishById), new {Id = fishRead.ID}, fishRead);
}
```

The result of posting a "Fish" data returns me a "Fish" entity model mapped to the "FishReadDTO" model but I would like to map it to the FishReadDTO but it return me a null value for property of "category" and "fish" in the Fish DTO model itself. Here is an example of it

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Test 3",
    "description": "Test 3",
    "weightKg": 76.25,
    "stock": 10,
    "price": 50.0,
    "category": null,
    "seller": null
}
```

Here's what I want which uses the FishDTO when getting a single "Fish" entity model mapped to the DTO which is working via the API method called "GetFishById(int id)". You can refer the method in my controller code posted.

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Northern Pike",
    "description": "A predatorial fish found in the waters of canal and rivers",
    "weightKg": 76.25,
    "stock": 10,
    "price": 50.0,
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "category": "Salt Water/Sea Fish"
    },
    "seller": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "AdrianJ",
        "name": "Adrian Joseph",
        "email": "adrianjoseph@efishing.com"
    }
}
```

Is there any way to basically get the "category" and "seller" being mapped and not getting null?

**Note that while using the "GetByFishId(int id)" API method which invoked my "FishRepository", without using the ".Include(...)" method in the repository I still get the values for "category" and "seller", the issue is at the API method where I create/post a new Fish which is this method"

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Fish> CreateFish(FishCreateDTO fishCreateDTO)
```

" into my database and it returns me a 201 Created using "CreatedAtRoute" is when I received the response of a "FishReadDTO" with null values of "category" and "seller" only.**

Comment: are you certain that `category` and `seller` are not null coming out of `_repository.GetFishById(id)`?

Comment: Yes, it does come out from _repository.GetFishById(id) just as the intented JSON response above

Comment: could it be because your ActionResult for posting returns `<Fish>` and not `< FishDTO>`?

Comment: Let me try that and then I'll let you know

Comment: Sorry @stackoverfloweth it's the same response giving me null on both attributes

Comment: really feels like those values are null coming out of repository, I'd put in a breakpoint and get eyes on that

Comment: Can you post how you set up the relations (`DbContext.OnModelConfiguring`)?

Comment: @abdusco I don't use Fluent API for the relations. I use conventions based on EF Core to set up one to many between the "Category" and the "Fish". Also each "Fish" has one to one relationship with "User" which in this case is the "seller" attribute. Take a look at this link for more https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx

Comment: @AdrianJoseph That's ok. I was curious to as to how could a relation not get loaded with `.Include()`. The only culprit I could think of was maybe a wrong configuration somewhere.

Comment: @abdusco yeah that's where I'm looking for it but couldn't find though

Comment: @abdusco, see the method `GetFishById`. Foreign entities are implicitly included in the select.

Comment: @vernou I doubt it. I can't find any reference to EF loading related data _implicitly_ with a `.Select`. Do you have a source on that?

Comment: @AdrianJoseph, I often see this error because few classes have the same name. Maybe you can try with class full name (namespace + class) in `EFishingProfile`

Comment: @abdusco, I don't find a source... but I tested and the projection automatically include nested entities.

Comment: @vernou it's a result of EF populating properties that have already been loaded whether you `.Include()` them or not.

Comment: I think we need more detail. Can you show `CreateFish`, `FishReadDTO`, `FishCreateDTO` and `FishCategoryReadDTO`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch relations from the database. When you load an entity from the DbContext, its relations are not loaded, so you get `null`.

In your repository, if you change

```cs
_databaseContext.Fishes
        .Where(fish => fish.ID.Equals(id))
```

to

```cs
_databaseContext.Fishes
        .Include(e => e.Category)
        .Include(e => e.Seller)
        .FirstOrDefault(fish => fish.ID.Equals(id))
```

then DbContext will load those relations and navigation properties `Category` and `Seller` will be populated. Then AutoMapper can map those objects to DTOs like you expect.

For reference, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)

Comment: I did that, but still the same responses when mapping to the DTO

Comment: `ProjectTo` fits better here.

Comment: @AdrianJoseph Remove `.Select(fish => new Fish() { ... }) in your repo, fetch the entity directly.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu You're right. But I find it often leads to complex SQL queries with redundant JOINs, whereas EF Core generates a more efficient and straightforward SQL. Fetching a couple more columns isn't as bad as a bad SQL that thrashes the server or prevents index usage.

Comment: That's just poor usage. Because AM doesn't generate any SQL, EF does, and AM only requests what's in your DTOs. But because things are not explicit, you do need to be aware :)

Comment: @abdusco So, in my repository just make a "FirstOrDefault(...)" to fetch the entity directly? Is that what you meant?

Comment: @AdrianJoseph, yes. With `.Include(...)`s, of course. See my answer for reference

Comment: I did use .Include(...) but it doesn't make any changes to the response. Since my controller that does [HttpPost] when it returns a 201 Created which is CreatedAtRoute, that's when the response contains null for "category" and "seller". This can be proven when retrieving one particular data which is GetFishById API method where the "category" and "seller" has a value but not in the [HttpPost]

Comment: Does the database actually have values for those columns? You must have those filled with foreign keys of CategoryId & Seller Id for `.Include()` to work.

Comment: It has. Hence, that's why when I input GetFishById() the Id of a fish, it return's me a single "FishDTO" and in which has "category" and "seller" attribute values in it. And this thing operation works well without the ".Include()" in my repository since it maps well with my FishDTO. It is only when a post/create a new "Fish" using "HttpPost" and upon invoking "_repository.SaveChanges()", it returns me the newly created "Fish" entity mapped to the "FishDTO" where the "category" and the "seller" has null value in it.

Comment: When you debug, do you ever get a non-null value for `Fish.Seller` in your repository?

Comment: Yes when I debug, I get a non-null value of Fish.Seller. I've updated my question for better understanding. I followed one of the tutorials from this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmvcAzHpsk8&t=9038s